# vsto outlook get account email address which received email

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

Consider this situation: in my outlook I have two accounts my_name@gmail.com (default) and my_nyme@hotmail.com . If someone sends one e-mail message to booth my addresses I’ll end up with two email in my outlook inbox.  Is it possible (using VSTO for Outlook) to differentiate which email message was received for gmail.com domain and which for yahoo.com?
I have this

String emailAddress = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address;

but it's always my_name@gmail.com. If I iterate Outlook.MailItem.Recipients I’ll get booth my email address and can’t resolve which of them is true recipient.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate them if you have got the single delivery store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MailItem.SendUsingAccount property - it will point to the account used to receive the message.

Comment: MailItem.SendUsingAccount returns 'System.__ComObject'?

Comment: No, it returns Account object - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's it! How foolish I was to oversee that it returns account object. I treated it as string. Anyway thanks again.